# Share values across child and parent component Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have two component (two datatables) and I want to share the v-model across them. I know how I can update the parent from the child, but can do the same from the parent?
Here is some code:

```
<ChildDataTable 
           v-model="childselected"
           @selected="selected=$event" >
</ChildDataTable>
<ParentDataTable  
           v-model="parentselected">
</ChildDataTable>
```

This way when I change childselected the parent receive and it works well but, there is a way I can modify it from the parent and it will be received from the child at the same time?

Thank you.

Comment: These are not parent and child components. They are siblings.

Answer (score 0):

The **reactivity** of Vue should update the variables. So you can change the two models in each component

```
<ChildDataTable 
           :parentselected="parentselected"
           v-model="childselected"
           @selected="selected=$event" >
</ChildDataTable>
<ParentDataTable  
           v-model="parentselected"
           :childselected="childselected">
</ChildDataTable>
```

Note: It is possible that when changing the model directly, you need a [setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)